# custom Button android like media player button

Tags: android, button, media-player

HI,

I'm trying to achieve a custom buttons . I'm wondering how I can achieve this with Android.

The result should look similar like this,

[image]

how I can make special shapes adjacent the problem it is because the image of each button must always be rectangle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom backgrounds (shapes, colors, etc..) using xml drawables.

You should check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) and the [samples, like this one](http://envyandroid.com/archives/242/drawable-gradient-lines-android):

Comment: yes you are right I had already created my  custom buttons (png) but i'am obliged to have buttons source rectangle. i want to create like windows media player.

Comment: you can set the corner radius for the rectangle, so you can achieve a round button by setting the radius half of the button width.